# Cisco Call Manager LUA Normalization script not changing SDP

Tags: lua, normalization

Good day,

I am just getting my feet wet in LUA normalization scripting for cisco.

Im attempting to modify a private IP that appears in the c= header of the SDP (for a remote user), with the public-facing IP.

The background for this is that we are interfacing with redsky for e911 for our work-from-home users, via an internet SIP trunk configured on call manager. Test calls connect but have no audio. Redsky indicates we need to present the public IP in the SDP, instead of the private IP, and since cubes arent used, etc, the only way I can see to do this is a LUA script to change those entries.

The first script Im trying is the most basic I can come up with (The IPs have been changed to protect the guilty - theyre not even possible mostly!)

```
trace.enable()
trace.format("SCRIPT HAS STARTED ")
function M.outbound_INVITE(msg)
  trace.format("message captured: ")
  local sdp = msg:getSdp()
  trace.format("sdp captured :%s",sdp)
  if sdp
  then
    trace.format("------ IN IF Then ------")
    local InIP4_line = sdp:getLine("c=","IN IP4 172.200.300.400")
    trace.format("InIP4_line captured: ",InIP4_line)
    if InIP4_line
    then
      trace.format("------ IN IF Then IP4 ------")
      --Replace ip v4 addr with pub-facing IP. 
      --escaped using % when using gsub.
      InIP4_line = InIP4_line:gsub("172.200.300.400", "201.301.401.164")
      trace.format("InIP4_line Modified: ",InIP4_line)
      sdp = sdp:modifyLine("c=", "172.200.300.400", InIP4_line)
      trace.format("sdp modified: ",sdp)
      msg:setSdp(sdp)
    end
    trace.format("After end IF inIP4")
  end
  trace.format("After end IF SDP")
end
trace.format("After end function")
return M
```

When using this script, making a test call from my home jabber phone, with my vpn IP matching the 172.200.300.400, then gathering logs from RTMT,
I see the call - the c= record matches the c=IN IP4 172.200.300.400  in the 'Before outbound SIP Normalization' in the logs, but always shows 'After inbound (no change) SIP Normalization'

I added some debugging trace msgs (as seen above) and those seem to indicate its failing the 'if sdp' check:

```
    Line 12399: 15774237.003 |10:23:15.353 |AppInfo  |//SIPLua/Script/trace_output: SCRIPT HAS STARTED 
    Line 12400: 15774237.004 |10:23:15.353 |AppInfo  |//SIPLua/Script/trace_output: After end function
    Line 12401: 15774237.005 |10:23:15.353 |AppInfo  |//SIPLua/Info/Load and Init successful: device USEmergRedSky-SIP script RedskyNormlyzInIP4 module M max mem 1024000 warning mem 819200
    Line 12402: 15774237.006 |10:23:15.354 |AppInfo  |//SIPLua/Info/Device:USEmergRedSky-SIP Script:RedskyNormlyzInIP4 -- base script memory 19604 user script memory 1616
```

As you can see, there are also some memory statements but Im not sure if those are errors or information.

I also see this error:
 `//SIPLua/Error/SipContexts_removeContext: call contexts object is missing`

The only reference I can find for it suggests increasing the memory and number of lines allowed for the script - which I increased to 1000 KB and 2000 instructions - which seems more than enough to me, but Im still seeing it.

also another very general question:
if the invite is coming from a remote call manager phone (jabber in this case) into call manager - then out the trunk, is that characterized as an inbound_invite or outbound_invite?

So HomeJabberUserOnCiscoCM --> CiscoCM --> CiscoTrunkwNormalizeScript --> Internet --> Redsky

I am presuming Im making some basic mistakes that perhaps someone can point out to me.

Thanks for your help